# Trying to use insertion sort to sort a list of dictionaries with the value of its child (python)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

My dictionaries are from a database but for this example imagine i have two dictionairies

```
    dictionary1 = {
        "score": str(percentageScore),       #totalScore
        "date": str(today),      #today
        "title": str(title),   #title
        "timestamp": str(timestamp)  #timestamp to display results in order
    }
```

The timestamp is an integer and i would like to use it to sort a python list containing multiple dictionaries like this, in descending order based on the timestamp integer.

I have tried to do this with:

```
sortedScores = [dictionary1, dictionary2, dictionary3]

            for i in range(1, len(sortedScores)):
                sortKey = sortedScores[i['timestamp']]
                j = (i - 1)
                while (j <= 0) and (sortKey < (sortedScores[j])['timestamp']):
                    sortedScores[j+1] = sortedScores[j]
                    j -= 1
                sortedScores[j+1] = sortKey
```

However i am currently getting the error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1):

```py
sortedScores = sorted([dictionary1,dictionary2,dictionary3],key=lambda x:int(x['timestamp']),reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in "i['timestamp']"
when you write for i in range (1, len(...)), i become an integer between 1 and the other number. So i[timestamp] doesn't have any sense. Try to correct this :)